# PYTHON - StaleElementReferenceException for enabled element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on the `"Next page"` in `Python-Selenium`. The element and its path are seen, the buttom is being clicked but after clicking an error is shown:

```
"StaleElementReferenceException:stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"
```

My code so far:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(\
                           (By.XPATH, butn)))
print (element.is_enabled())
while True and element.is_enabled()==True:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(butn).click()
```

The error is one `element.is_enabled()==True` after clicking

Can someone help?

Comment: The `staleElementReferenceException` has nothing to do with whether or not the element is enabled, if that's what you are thinking. It occurs when you define an element, load a new DOM (eg after clicking a link), then try to reuse the element.

Comment: Could you provide us with a website link ? (on a first glance I would say that you want `element.is_displayed()` instead of `is_enabled`).

Comment: when you search elements in Selenium then it doesn't keep full objects but only references to object in browser DOM. And when you click then browser create new DOM and old reference are incorrect and you have find elements again.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you search elements in Selenium then it doesn't keep full objects but only references to objects in DOM in browser. And when you `click` then browser creates new DOM and old references are incorrect and you have to find elements again.

Something like this

```
# find first time
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, butn)))
print(element.is_enabled())

while element.is_enabled():
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(butn).click()
    # find again after changes in DOM
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, butn)))
    print(element.is_enabled())
```

Comment: That's it !! Thanks alot @furas